# Why forecast(model, h=2) function returns NA value (model is from R auto.arima())?

Tags: r, arima, forecast

This R code predicts sp500 with arima model,

```
rm(list=ls())
load("StockData.Rdata")
library(seasonal)
library(forecast)
library(tseries)
library(astsa)
sp500 = StockData[,1]
model = auto.arima(sp500,
                     max.p=52,max.q=52,max.d=52,
                     seasonal = TRUE,
                     lambda = "auto", biasadj = TRUE)
predict = forecast(model,biasadj=TRUE, h=2)
```

Here, I want to use auto.arima with Box-Cox transformation, so I set `lambda = "auto"`, and `biasadj = TRUE`. However, the predicted value has mean `NaN`:

```
> forecast(model,biasadj=TRUE, h=2)
    Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
209            NaN -0.1278079 0.1206801 -0.1962931 0.1890652
210            NaN -0.1278079 0.1206801 -0.1962931 0.1890652
```

I have checked some GitHub questions and some people say that it is because there is NA value in the residual so the point forecast is NaN. However, the residual in `model` doesn't contain `NaN` so it should not be the case. So, how can I solve that?

Also, why is the predicted value same for t=209 and t=210?

Comment: It's difficult to debug without having access to your data (see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips on how to do that). How does your `model` fit the data? On a side note: Some of your `auto.arima` parameters are not very sensible; for example, setting the maximum degree of differencing to 52 is just nonsense. Obviously it depends on the area of work and the underlying data generation process but I'd be suspicious of any d>3 ARIMA fit. The `max.p` and `max.q` args also seem way too high.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I upload the data: https://github.com/118020071/bankcruptcy_data/blob/main/StockData.RData

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling there is a misunderstanding about what `biasadj` does, but I think you need to take a step back and inspect the original data.

Let's plot `sp500`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = seq_along(sp500), y = sp500), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

A cursory inspection suggests no seasonality and no drift/linear trend; there may be some indication of heteroskedasticity which may warrant a Box-Cox transformation.

Keeping model parsimony in mind, I would start with a default call to `auto.arima` allowing for a automatic Box-Cox transformation

```r
library(forecast)
model <- auto.arima(sp500, lambda = "auto")
#Series: sp500 
#ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean 
#Box Cox transformation: lambda= 0.7637886 
#
#Coefficients:
#    ma1     mean
#-0.1142  -1.3103
#s.e.   0.0582   0.0041
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 0.00548:  log likelihood=308.93
#AIC=-611.86   AICc=-611.77   BIC=-601.18
```

`auto.arima` determines the optimal model to be ARIMA(0,0,1) on Box-Cox-transformed data with lambda = 0.76, which corresponds to a simple first-order moving average model MA(1). This seems to be consistent with the earlier visual assessment.

When forecasting, `forecast` will automatically show estimates on the original scale, see e.g.

```r
autoplot(forecast(model, h = 10))
```

[image]

Comment: After several trails, I just find that biasadj is just for adjusting the training data according to the lambda value, and adding lambda=model$lambda into forecast() parameters will give valid mean not NaNs.

Comment: @RayJio No, that is not how `biasadj` works. `forecast` will give values on the original (i.e. pre-Box-Cox transformed) scale either way. `biasadj` introduces an adjustment that ensures that back-transformed values correspond to the mean of the forecast distribution rather than the median. You can find some details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974566/bias-adjustment-for-the-box-cox-back-transformation), [here](https://harlecin.netlify.app/post/box-cox-and-other-transformations/) and [here](https://otexts.com/fpp2/transformations.html).

Comment: [continued] If the forecast distribution is symmetric (e.g. more or less normal) then there is nothing to adjust, and forecasts with and without bias adjustment will be (more or less) the same. More importantly in your case is that there is really not much to forecast here. Data don't show any seasonality, and BC-transformed data suggests a stationary process with a weak MA(1) term.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Now I can successfully forecast.